# Sitecore Bulk create items with event disablers taking more time to visible in CM content editor tree

Tags: sitecore8

> HI 
>   I am trying to create bulk items in CM server using the below code. This code runs on a windows service based application, once this code completes all the newly created items can be viewed in sitecore search only,`enter code here but it is not displayed in content editor tree, it is taking some more hours like 6hrs to display in content editor tree. please let me know whether any other code is necessary to populate the items immediately in CM - master server once the items are created.

```
 Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite("shell");
 using (new SecurityDisabler())
 using (new SyncOperationContext())
 using (new ProxyDisabler())
 using (new EventDisabler())
 using (new DatabaseCacheDisabler())
 using (new BulkUpdateContext())
 {
  Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Indexing.Enabled = false;

      //Business operations starts here      

  Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Indexing.Enabled = true;

  }
```

Comment: Remove `EventDisabler` - this one tell Sitecore that you will tak care of all the events like updating cachces and indexing items.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  If i remove EventDisablers then the whole process of creating sitecore items is taking much more time for my case, now by using above code i can able to create 1000 of items in a minute, please let me know for other solution